# src\main\resources\db.properties (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I tried to deploy my application to Heroku and get this exception:

```
Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\db.properties (No such file or directory)
```

I tried different ways, but I didn't find anything suitable, the error still haunts me :(

Main class:

```
package com.bot.ranksystem_20.application;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.bot.ranksystem_20"})
public class Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }

}
```

This is data base configuration:

```
package com.bot.ranksystem_20.configuration;

import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
public class ConfigurationDataBase {
    @SneakyThrows
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        try {
            properties.load(new FileInputStream(new File("src\\main\\resources\\db.properties")));
            String dbUrl = properties.getProperty("db.url");
            String dbUsername = properties.getProperty("db.username");
            String dbPassword = properties.getProperty("db.password");;
            String driverClassName = properties.getProperty("db.driverClassName");
            dataSource.setUsername(dbUsername);
            dataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);
            dataSource.setUrl(dbUrl);
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }

        return dataSource;
    }


    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

}
```

This if my db.property:

```
db.username=-
db.password=-
db.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
db.url =jdbc:postgresql://-:5432/-
```

And this is my long suffering pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bot</groupId>
    <artifactId>ranksystem_2.0</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ranksystem_2.0</name>
    <description>Rank System for Discord Server</description>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <logentries-appender>RELEASE</logentries-appender>
        <spring.version>3.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0_168</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>application.properties</include>
                <include>db.properties</include>
                <include>titleChannels.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>heroku-sdk-parent</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                <version>3.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appname>ranksystem20</appname>
                    <includetarget>false</includetarget>
                    <includes>
                        <include>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </includes>
                    <jdkversion>1.8</jdkversion>
                    <processtypes>
                        <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -jar
                            ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</web>
                    </processtypes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I will be glad to receive your suggestions!

Comment: _Just to start_, you seem to be trying to use a 7-year-old version of Spring with the latest Spring Boot for some reason. Furthermore, the whole point of Boot is that it handles this stuff for you; put `spring.datasource.*` in your `application.properties` and you're finished.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- can you show example, please?

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/ https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like said in a comment you should let Spring Boot handle these properties by putting the content of `db.properties` into `application.properties` where it is picked up automatically.

But if you insist on using manual configuration at least consider using a tad bit more modern approach.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
public class Config {

@Value("${db.driverClassName}")
String driverClassName;

@Value("${db.url}")
String url;

@Value("${db.username}")
String username;

@Value("${db.password}")
String password;

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    var dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUsername(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    return dataSource;
}
}
```